# Meaning of "~" (tilde) symbol in C++?

Tags: c++

```
// AirlineTicket.h

class AirlineTicket
{
public:
  AirlineTicket();

  ~AirlineTicket();
     
  int          getNumberOfMiles();
    
private:
  int          mNumberOfMiles;
};
```

I want now what is the meaning of  `~AirlineTicket();` in this code?
I don't know the meaning of `~` (tilde).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is the destructor.
It gets called when you destroy (reaching end of scope, or calling `delete` to a pointer to) the instance of the object.

Comment: Or when deletion automatically occurs.

Comment: Note that `~` can also denote bitwise not in a different context.

Answer (score 27):

In the context you're using it, it defines a destructor.

In *other* context such as the following one, it's also called bitwise negation (complement):

```
int a = ~100;
int b = ~a;
```

Output: ([ideone](http://ideone.com/5YrkC))

```
-101
100
```

Comment: @Sujoy: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Nawaz: I mean that in the given question `~` clearly is not used for bitwise negation.

Comment: @Nawaz "what is the meaning of ~AirlineTicket(); in this code?"  is not answered by "bitwise negation", it is a destructor

Comment: @Sujoy: If you read my answer carefully, then I didn't say that either.

Comment: @Nawaz: and i said that it is "not in this context"

Comment: @Daniel: That is not the question. The question is : what is the meaning of `~` in C++?. And the OP sees it's usage in one context, I gave him other context  where the same sign is used with entirely different meaning!

Comment: @Nawaz that is *literally* the question, I am quoting the asker, they're asking what it means **in this code** and your answer doesn't address that

Comment: @Nawaz this is not a place to dump random related information, answers are supposed to address the question being asked, yours does not - regardless of whatever caveats you put in your explanation

Comment: @Daniel: It's not RANDOM. It's the SAME SIGN. If I were to talk about design patterns or politics, it would have been RANDOM. It seems, for you things are either same or random, but not somehow related!

Comment: I'll agree it's not random, but bitwise negation on signed integers depending on the integers representation, I would have preferred a better example...

Comment: @Matthieu: Feel free to edit my post if you've better example. Hopefully, I learn something from it. :-)

Comment: +1 It's important that this answer is on this page, or the OP might have gone away thinking that the tilde -- which he's _never seen before in C++ -- is only used as part of a destructor's name. And that's just not true. (Though in order to make it a really decent answer, you ought to have spoken about destructors, too.)

Comment: @Tomalak: That's very repetitive, as almost everyone has spoken about destructor. So I wrote what others didn't.

Comment: @Nawaz: Answers should be self-contained, no? Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Comment: @Tomalak: But it makes most part of the answer repetitive and so uninteresting. Readers might not be interested to read the complete post. If that is so, then I don't see any advantage by making it "self-contained".

Comment: +1 Came in from a search looking for the meaning of tilde in C++ code I was examining. In my case it *was* a bitwise operation. Having both answers here was helpful.

Answer (score 7):

`~` signs that it is a destructor and when ever the object goes out of scope, corresponding destructor is called.

**When the destructor is called ?**

Taking an example -

```
#include <iostream> 
class foo
{
    public:
    void checkDestructorCall() ;
    ~foo();
};

void foo::checkDestructorCall()
{
    foo objOne;   // objOne goes out of scope because of being a locally created object upon return of checkDestructorCall
}

foo:: ~foo()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor called \t" << this << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo obj;    // obj goes of scope upon return of main
    obj.checkDestructorCall();
    return 0;
}
```

Results on my system:

```
Destructor called   0xbfec7942  
Destructor called   0xbfec7943
```

This example just serves to indicate when a destructor is called. But destructor is written only when the class manages resources.

**When class manages resources?**

```
#include <iostream> 
class foo
{

    int *ptr;

    public:
    foo() ; // Constructor
    ~foo() ;

};

foo:: foo()
{
     ptr = new int ; // ptr is managing resources.
                     // This assignment can be modified to take place in initializer lists too.
}

foo:: ~foo()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor called \t" << this << "\n";
    delete ptr ; // Returning back the resources acquired from the free store.
                 // If this isn't done, program gives memory leaks.
}

int main()
{
    foo *obj = new foo;
    // obj is pointing to resources acquired from free store. Or the object it is pointing to lies on heap. So, we need to explicitly call delete on the pointer object.

    delete obj ;  // Calls the ~foo
    return 0;
}
```

Results on my system:

```
Destructor called   0x9b68008
```

And in the program, you posted I don't see a need to write destructor. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 4):

It's the class destructor.  You might want to pick up an introductory text on C++ development, as destructors are a fundamental concept in OOP.  There is a good reference site [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/), and the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) is another good resource.

Comment: Better yet, check out the [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

`~AirlineTicket();` is the destructor for the class AirlineTicket

see [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr380.htm) for further reference

The destructor is called when you delete the object of that class, to free any memory allocated or resources being used by the object.

Answer (score 1):

`~` introduces a destructor.  It's used because (a) it was available, ad (b) `~` is one (of several) mathematical notation for "not".

Answer (score 1):

This indicates destructor of class.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr380.htm